# Google Play Game Service Integration Issue iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have been able to integrate the broken Google Play Services with unity iOS Project to an extent. I downloaded files from [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/). Lots of header files were missing, so I downloaded header files from [Robovm iOS Bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/google-play-game-services). I have included all necessary bundles and frameworks, but still getting following compiler errors:

[image]

The files mentioned in the figure are framework header files, I have already given path in build settings.

Moreover, there is neither definition file for headers nor any library provided by google, then how will I resolve this issue?

Please give me some directions to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions and the required libraries for building can be found on the [plugin repository readme page](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#ios-setup):

Specifically you need:
Google Plus SDK for iOS
Google Play Games C++ SDK

There are some compiler flag settings you also need to modify, so pay special attention to that.